# Onboard wifi on MSI board not working in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, network-adapter, wifi-driver

I have a new motherboard from MSI (Z690 Tomhawk wifi ddr4). The onboard wifi does not work in ubuntu 20.04
I have only ubuntu (no dual boot with windows). Fast boot and secure boot is disabled in BIOS settings. I tried installing drivers from [Intel website](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/wireless.html) It did not work.

following is the output of `sudo lshw -C network` :

```
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
   description: Network controller
   product: Intel Corporation
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 14.3
   bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
   version: 11
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:42f1c000-42f1ffff


*-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: Intel Corporation
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
   logical name: enp4s0
   version: 03
   serial: d8:bb:c1:94:79:8c
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igc driverversion=5.13.0-28-generic firmware=1073:8754 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
   resources: irq:19 memory:42b00000-42bfffff memory:42c00000-42c03fff
```

Here is the output of `lspci`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 4660 (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 4680 (rev 0c)
00:06.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 464d (rev 02)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 464f (rev 02)
00:0a.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 467d (rev 01)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 7ae0 (rev 11)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Device 7aa7 (rev 11)
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 7af0 (rev 11)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 7ae8 (rev 11)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device 7ae2 (rev 11)
00:1a.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 7ac8 (rev 11)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 7ab8 (rev 11)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 7abb (rev 11)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 7a84 (rev 11)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 7ad0 (rev 11)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 7aa3 (rev 11)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 7aa4 (rev 11)
01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device a809
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Intel Corporation SSD 660P Series (rev 03)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Device 15f3 (rev 03)
```

Does anyone know how to solve this ?

update:

After upgrading kernel to 5.16rc7 , bluetooth now works but still no wifi.

Comment: Please add the relevant output of `lsusb` or `lspci` containing the model number of the nework card.

Comment: @mashuptwice updated the question with lspci output

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1377110/intel-ax201-wi-fi-6-and-ethernet-wont-work-ubuntu-20-04-and-21-10

Comment: @mashuptwice I tried updating the kernel. It did not work. I installed windows just to confirm it's the same network card and I can confirm it's the same (Intel AX201)

Comment: Well, there was much more information in this thread than just the kernel update, for example this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1244745/ubuntu-20-04-intel-network-connectivity-issue-bug-in-igc

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by implementing the Ubuntu22.04. I guess that Ubuntu20.04 doesn't has the latest support for mag-z690-tomohawk-wifi motherboard. Hope it helps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: After several updates it's working properly now.